# Finding the widest angle to shoot a soccer ball from the sideline using optimization

Tags: trigonometry, optimization

[image: soccer field]

I'm trying to do an independent project for my Math class, but I was stuck and couldn't figure out how to use optimization to find position along the sideline that gives the widest angle to shoot. As in the picture, A and C demonstrate positions that provide smaller angle to shoot, while B provides a wider angle to shoot.  I tried using law of cosine, but because both sides of triangles change every times I didn't know how to apply optimization to it :(

if anyone know, please help, any suggestion would be appreciate

Comment: Your diagram is wrong! It shows the angles subtended by the goal area, not the goal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using just trigonometry and the derivative:

Let $h_0$ be the distance from the corner of the field to the near goalpost, and $h_1$ be the distance from the corner to the far goalpost.  (The goal is $h_1-h_0$ wide.)  And let $x$ be the distance from the corner to your kicking point on the sideline.  The angle you want to maximize is: $$f(x)=\arctan(h_1/x)-\arctan(h_0/x).$$
To find the maximum you need $f'(d)=0$, this is necessary but not sufficient.  Fortunately $\arctan$ has an easy derivative: $\frac{d}{dx}\arctan(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$, so we can calculate by the chain rule
$$\frac{d}{dx}\arctan(h/x)=-\frac{h}{h^2+x^2}.$$  So for $f'(x)=0$ you must have $$\frac{h_0}{h_0^2+x^2}=\frac{h_1}{h_1^2+x^2},$$ which a little algebra solves (for its positive solution) as $$x=\sqrt{\frac{h_0h_1^2-h_1h_0^2}{h_1-h_0}}=\sqrt{h_0h_1}.$$
It's apparent that this is in fact the maximizer you are looking for.

Comment: It might be good to point out how to check it truly is a maximum rather than say "it's apparent...".  A striking example of a failure to verify that a solution to $f' = 0$ truly is a maximum rather than a minimum is at http://vozderazon.tripod.com/lit/stealthbomber.html and http://pages.iu.edu/~dpthurst/F10/CalcIII/StealthBomber.pdf.

Answer (score 3):

Construct a circle that passes through each goalpost, and is tangent to the sideline. Then $B$ is the point where the circle touches the sideline.

This is because the goalposts subtend the same angle for all points on the circle (as depicted in [this GIF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aArcCapable.gif) from the Wikipedia article [Inscribed angle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle)). Points $A$ and $C$ lie outside this circle, so they see a smaller angle.

To find the centre of the circle, draw a line bisecting the pitch lengthwise and find the point on this line that is distance $h$ from a goalpost, where $2h$ is the width of the pitch (use Pythagoras for this). And from the centre of the circle, you can drop a perpendicular to the sideline to find $B$.

**Edited to add:** Jeff Snider has answered your question using a completely different method. I suggest that you try to verify that our different approaches give the same answer.